# Manually measuring layout before used in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to measure the height of some layouts ahead of them before used (in recyclerview). All the layout either have wrap_content size or specific dp set on it (i.e. not dependent on the parent view).

I made a function as below. 
It works well for layout that is purely wrap_content size, and doesn't have any layout within that has defined size (i.e. all wrap_content)

```
private float measureViewHeight(int resource) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(resource, null);
    view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    return (float) view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

But if the layout is containing some layouts that has specific dp height defined, the measurement return is not inaccurate. How should I fix my function so it returns the right value?

**Update**
With the answer from @shhp, the and also fixing prelollipop crash... the updated answer would be use the following

```
private float measureViewHeight(int resource) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(resource, null);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    return (float) view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of `View.measure` have special meaning and you should call `MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec` to get the parameter.

Replace

```
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

with

```
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```

The runnable will run when the view is layed out, and should give correct measurements.

Also, you don't need to inflate the views again in the measure method. You are wasting resources and it is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can't do it your way, because I need to pre-calculate each layout height before used in recyclerview (i.e. before it is being layout). Hence the view will not be shown. I know inflating it this is not conventional, but can't find other better way to get the view measured before it got layout. Do share if you have a way to measure a viewholder height before we have the recyclerview setup. Thanks.